# How to leave a job that isn't a good fit?

Tags: professionalism, job-change

I'm currently working at a company, and after two and a half months I've come to the conclusion that it isn't a good fit for me.  I've been taking a look around and interviewing with other companies here and there, but haven't been rushing it since I do have a job (that's good) and the only downside to it is I just plain don't like the problems i'm presented with, nor the culture and some of their HR Policies. Notably, I am gay and their harassment and non-discrimination policies omit sexual orientation as a protected group (at the state-level, it isn't protected either).

I've had a few companies indicate they may extend an offer soon.  From what i've learned of these companies, they seem to be a much better fit for me in terms of problems i'd be working on and culture.

If these offers come in, how do I explain to my boss "hey, its just not a good fit" without having to get too detailed on the why, since I know he won't let the topic drop until he has an answer?

Comment: "From what i've learned of these companies, they seem to be a much better fit for me in terms of problems i'd be working on and culture." do they also have the harassment and non-discrimination policies that you seek?

Comment: What is a "protected group" in this context? We don't have those here - harassment and discrimination is simply harassment and discrimination regardless of the target

Comment: Are you actually being harassed over your sexual orientation, or are you reacting only to the wording of the HR policy document?

Comment: @HorusKol protected groups are groups federally protected against discrimination at a federal level. Gender, religion, veteran status and age are examples of these.

Comment: @A.I.Breveleri Not directly.  The concern is that inevitably, people are going to find out, and from what i've heard that will create problems when seeking promotions.

Comment: In that case - is it normal for a company to name additional protected groups over and above the federally mandated ones?

Comment: I ask because, if the HR policy is no worse than anywhere else, and since you're only 2.5 months into the job, you're really only left with the culture as a reason to leave. Is it that bad that you must jump so soon after starting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest that focusing on the work assignment side of things may be less awkward.

> You: "It's not a good fit for me here"
>
> Boss: "In what way?"
>
> You: "I'm less interested in the work than I thought I'd be."

If you do want to lay the groundwork for improvement for protection based on sexual orientation, I'd advise being open about that policy being a contributing factor.  If they don't know that this is a problem impacting their retention they won't put effort into fixing it.

Answer (score 3):

Adam, you're not obligated to explain anything to your boss.  It's sounding as if attempting to do so may cause you more personal distress than you really want to cope with.  People leave jobs every day for no shortage of reasons, so this isn't a unique situation.

If you're really going to do it, get focused on finding your next opportunity.  But ***this time***, ask the right questions before you change jobs, so you don't jump out of the frying pan and into the fire.  Examine your offers carefully, and pick the right one for you.  When you get your written offer letter, turn in your resignation and get on with your life.

Again, don't worry about your boss.  Your boss will get over it.  You're not doing anything wrong by keeping your mouth shut on reasons you're leaving.

Comment: Yeah, i learned =that= lesson.  Honestly, i found out about the policy on day two, was fine for a few days and then its just been nagging me every day since.  In every one of these interviews, one of my questions to the interviewer has been "May I have a copy of your discrimination policy" because I'm really, really bothered deep down by that.

Answer (score 1):

Once you give your notice, you can just say "hey, it wasn't a good fit" without providing any more details if you prefer it that way. Your boss can't force the information out of you if you don't wish to provide it.

That said, is there any harm in giving details?

Ultimately, it's completely your choice, at least in the US.